# How to prevent thumbnail image stretching?

Tags: css, image, wordpress, stretching

I've tried several ways to keep images from stretching in this plugin.

```
.wpbdmthumbs img {
 max-height: 150px;
 max-width: 150px;
}

.wpbdmthumbs {
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
}
```

and this

```
.wpbdmthumbs img {
 max-height:400px;
 height: exp<b></b>ression(this.width > 400 ? 400: true);
 max-width:400px;
 width: exp<b></b>ression(this.width > 400 ? 400: true);
}
```

I have also tried this javascript (idk js, so may be wrong, got it from another forum)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(path)
{
temp=new Image();
temp.onload=function(){
var w=temp.width;
var h=temp.height;
var cnt=document.getElementById("wpbdmthumbs");
var fitto=(w>h)?w:h;
var ratio=150/fitto;
temp.width *=ratio;
temp.height *=ratio;
wpbdmthumbs.appendChild(temp)
}
temp.src=path;
}
</script>
```

The thumbs are placed in a directory listing excerpt page by a Wordpress plugin called Business Directory. There is a setting that sets the main image for the listing to whatever size I want (300px is what I set), but then as the same image is used as the thumbnail in the excerpt and displays at the same size, which is too large for the excerpt page. So I have css to limit the thumb size in the excerpt to 150x150. The image is not distorted in the full listing but in the excerpt thumb it is distorted.

You can see it at http://www.nextinthewest.com

It stretches images wider to fill the 150 px width if it's taller than wide, and if it is wider than tall, it squishes in narrower but doesn't stretch it tall enough to fill the 150px height.

I may also be using the wrong selector, but I've tried several.

Maybe the plugin is telling the browser is 300px tall and wide and maybe any css is unable to work within that to prevent stretching.

Comment: Set widths and heights to auto then then assign max-widths and heights. Use !important to ensure they are respected. I just did this on the link you provided using google dev tools and it fixed the sretching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS if you want to over ride the CSS that is being generated by a plugin the the very rare correct use of `!important` is required. The benefit of correct use of `!important` is to over ride javascript generated CSS when directly editing the plugin is not possibile.

```
.wpbdmthumbs img {
 height: auto !important;
 width: auto !important;
 max-height: 150px !important;
 max-width: 150px !important;
}

.wpbdmthumbs {
 height: 150px !important;
 width: 150px !important;
}
```

Comment: This only worked if I took out the img reference. I didn't need the second part. It does require the max- notation. Thank you so much for leading me to the answer. The images are scaling now perfectly.

Comment: Correction, it works without the img reference and the second part, but it doesn't enforce the size of the container to be 150px wide, and that is messing up the layout of the text to the right of the thumb. I understand that the img reference is supposed to control the image alone and the second part control the size of the container, but that isn't working. I need the left edge of the text to all line up for each listing. Looking forward to your suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually needed #wpbdp-view-listings-page .listing-details {width: 525px;float: right;} so it wouldn't mess up the full listing page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to bo of assistance. If this answer helped could you mark it as correct, thanks.